# Making webpages on the server accessible

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2

I have just set up a LAMP EC2 instance using rightscale when I got to the link:

"http://ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/"

I get the standard apache welcome page. Now on my server I have the directory '/var/www/html/' where I can put my 'publicly' viewable web-pages. I have added a directory in here with some php script which are now at:

"/var/www/html/newdir/somefilename.php"

When I go to:

"http://ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/newdir/somefilename.php"

The script doesnt run (php is working) - i.e. I get 'Not found' - i.e. cant even find the page. I have set permissions to the directory and file to 777 (using chmod).

Can anyone please tell me what I am not doing? I want to be able to run the php from a web browser.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Is there anything showing up in the apache logs?  Typically: /var/log/httpd/access_log or /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: I found the 

"/home/webapps" 

string in file 

"/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpapp.conf" 

using the command 

"find / -type f -print | xargs grep "/home/webapps/">> /tmp/bigsearch2.log 2>/dev/null"

So phpapp.conf contained the path to my public folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used the wrong document root. According to the Rightscale support site the the docume troot seems to be at `/home/webapps/$APPLICATION/current`. You may also take a look onto the [Rightscale Support site](http://support.rightscale.com/03-Tutorials/02-AWS/01-Beginner_Examples/4._Intermediate_Example#Add_RightScale_Credentials)