# Making webpages on the server accessible

Tags: php, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making webpages on the server accessible](https://serverfault.com/questions/160494/making-webpages-on-the-server-accessible)

I have just set up a LAMP EC2 instance using rightscale when I got to the link:

"http://ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/"

I get the standard apache welcome page. Now on my server I have the directory '/var/www/html/' where I can put my 'publicly' viewable web-pages. I have added a directory in here with some php script which are now at:

"/var/www/html/newdir/somefilename.php"

When I go to:

"http://ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/newdir/somefilename.php"

The script doesnt run (php is working) - i.e. I get 'Not found' - i.e. cant even find the page. I have set permissions to the directory and file to 777 (using chmod).

Can anyone please tell me what I am not doing? I want to be able to run the php from a web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you httpd.conf file. It seems to be a configuration issue with DocumentRoot.

IIRC, Apache on debian is set to have a DocumentRoot configured like this

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

If so, you can view your script via your browser with following URL:

http://ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/html/newdir/somefilename.php